# How to work shared database with code first

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

I would like to create a system like WordPress. I will have a lot of separate projects in the system *(they can be NuGet package or source codes)*. This projects should have their own tables also has some common tables too *(like user table)*. I tried to use entity framework code first but I couldn't succeed *(common tables led to conflicts)*. What is the best practises *(design strategy)* for this kind of projects in .net core?

I will explain with an example:
I have 2 projects. One of them lets say A. A project has a Dbcontext like => `ADbContext : IdentityDbContext`. It's using IdentityDbContext. That's mean I will have **aspnetuser** table. It has also different tables too(companies, cars etc.) and this all tables generating by entity framework code first. I have a couple of migration histories.

My other project using IdentityDbContext too => `FunnyNamesDbContext : IdentityDbContext`. It will create names with combining cars and names(I know silly but just for example).

This FunnyNameProject need a table named as "`fun_generatedNames`" and it is responsible creation of this table. It can not work without the car table or user table(or another strategy it can be create if they do not exist). Also, you should have an access user table via FunnyNamesDbContext too(`generatedName.User.Email`)

When I add funnynames project to my A project I will get some conflict errors about usertables are already exist.

If still couldn't explain well. You can think like, I want to build projects which they are responsible for their own tables like aspnetuser system or WordPress plugins.

Comment: If I can restate what you're asking; you want the software you create to be able to load plugins created by users who may store data in database tables, and you want all of them to use one database table but not allow the names to collide?

Comment: I can think of one way: register names for plugins; and prepend the table names with that plugin name on creation. So the people creating plugins use your interface for creating tables, and internally you match up the plugin's name with the table name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] (you get a badge!).

Comment: My bad sorry, I will update the question with more details and examples.